# Filezilla won't connect

Tags: ftp, firewall, filezilla

I am on a pc that uses filezilla. This pc is on a small network that has windows firewall installed. I de-activated windows firewall and I still cannot connect to my server.

The details are correct and filezilla actually logs in ok, but I can never see the server's directory listing etc and then I get this error message:

```
Response:   331 Password required for w00135469730.
Command:    PASS **************
Response:   230 User logged in.
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Extended features supported:
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Any ideas please? :(

Answer (score 1):

Try logging in anonymously to a known FTP website such as ftp.mozilla.org. This will at least let you find out if the problem lies on your end.

If you **can** log in to mozilla's FTP, then your password is likely incorrect for your account. Filezilla says you're logged in ok, but the "Could not connect to server" error means it actually bounced *back* after checking the password.

If you **can't** log in to mozilla's FTP, then you may have an issue with your router blocking the port or some other issue. My money is on the password, as I do this all the time by accident.

Comment: No joy I'm afraid, it wouldn't let me connect to mozilla. Password is fine

Connection timed out
Error: Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Resolving address of ftp.mozilla.org
Status: Connecting to 63.245.208.138:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...

Comment: Hmm. So if you put ftp.mozilla.org in the host and leave the username and password blank on the main filezilla screen, it won't got through? OK. Well, have you EVER had FTP working at your current location?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if filezilla is setup to use PASV mode?

Try using the windows command line FTP client - from a windows command line, do

```
ftp <hostname>
at name prompt: <username>
at password prompt: <password>
DIR
```

And see what happens. It might not work any better, but then again you might get some different errors that give you more clues. If that fails at the DIR (but you do get the name and password prompts), try a PASV before the DIR and see if that gives you any more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

```
* Open Filezilla, go to Edit -> Settings
* Click on Connection -> FTP: Choose Active
* Click on Connection -> FTP -> Active Mode: Select "Ask your operating system for the external IP address"
* Click on Connection -> FTP -> Passive Mode: Choose Fall Back to Active Mode
* Press OK.
```

Source: [Fix-for-Filezilla-Failing-to-Retrieve-Directory-Listing](http://www.nodans.com/index.cfm/2008/4/24/Fix-for-Filezilla-Failing-to-Retrieve-Directory-Listing)

Also, ensure your server allows you to connect remotely.